# Too many accounts have gotten banned from Instagram while scraping

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrape

I've been scraping Instagram using Instaloader for about 6 months. It worked really great, few banned accounts as excpected. But since last month too many accounts have gotten banned from Instagram.

I almost tried everything, slowing down the scraper using random sleep times, changing accounts after a few successful scrapes, using proxy servers and private proxies etc. But nothing worked.

Is there any solution for this problem?
Or is there any other libraries that can handle scraping likes for specific posts?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using these accounts for a week or two like a regular user (this is when Instagram tracks the actions or a new user more) then maybe try increasing your random wait times (about a photo a minute should be safe) and do not download content from the same user multiple times or you will be flagged